# Running a tensorflow model written in python for training and prediction from java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-recognition

I have retrained inception model for my own data set. Tho model is built in python and i now have the saved graph as .pb file and label file as .txt. Now i need to predict using this model for an image through java. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 3):

The TensorFlow team is developing a Java interface, but it is not stable yet. You can find the existing code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java and follow updates on its development here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5. You can take a look at [GraphTest.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/GraphTest.java), [SessionTest.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/SessionTest.java) and [TensorTest.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/TensorTest.java) to see how it is currently used (although, as explained, this may change in the future). Basically, you need to load the binary saved graph into a `Graph` object, create a `Session` with it and run it with the appropriate values (as `Tensor`s) to receive a `List<Tensor>` with the output. Put together from the examples in the source:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.tensorflow.Graph;
import org.tensorflow.Session;
import org.tensorflow.Tensor;

try (Graph graph = new Graph()) {
    graph.importGraphDef(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("saved_model.pb"));
    try (Session sess = new Session(graph)) {
        try (Tensor x = Tensor.create(1.0f);
             Tensor y = s.runner().feed("x", x).fetch("y").run().get(0)) {
            System.out.println(y.floatValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I used that worked read a `protobuf` file, ending with `.pb`.

```
try (SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("/tmp/model", "serve")) {
    Session sess = b.session();
    ...
    float[][]matrix = sess.runner()
        .feed("x", input)
        .feed("keep_prob", keep_prob)
        .fetch("y_conv")
        .run()
        .get(0)
        .copyTo(new float[1][10]);
    ...
}
```

The python code I used to save it was:

```
  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs = {'x': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)},
    outputs = {'y_conv': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y_conv)},
  )
  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("/tmp/model" )
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, 
       [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
       signature_def_map={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature}
   )
  builder.save()
```